# How to keep backend session information in Polymer SPA

Tags: polymer

I'd like to login to a RESTful back-end server written in Laravel5, with the single page front-end application leveraging Polymer's custom element.

In this system, the persistence(CRUD) layer lives in the server. So, authentication should be done at the server in responding to client's api request. When a request is valid, the server returns User object in JSON format including user's role for access control in client.

Here, **my questions is how I can keep the session, even when a user refreshes the front-end page?** Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue beyond Polymer, or even just single page apps. The question is how you keep session information in a browser. With SPAs it is a bit easier, since you can keep authentication tokens in memory, but traditional Web apps have had this issue since the beginning.

You have two things you need to do:

1. Tokens: You need a user token that indicates that this user is authenticated. You want it to be something that cannot be guessed, else someone can spoof it. So the token better not be "jimsmith" but something more reliable. You have two choices. Either you can have a randomly generated token which the server stores, so that when presented on future requests, it can validate the token. This is how just most session managers work in app servers like nodejs sessions or Jetty session or etc. The alternative is to do something cryptographic so that the server only needs to validate mathematically, not check in a store to see if the token is valid. I did that for node in http://github.com/deitch/cansecurity but there are various options for it.
2. Storage: You need some way to store the tokens client-side that does not depend on JS memory, since you expect to reload the page.

There are several ways to do client-side storage. The most common by far is cookies. Since the browser stores them without your trying too hard, and presents them whenever you access the domain that the cookie is registered for, it is pretty easy to do. Many client-side and server-side auth libraries are built around them.

An alternative is html5 local storage. Depending on your target browsers and support, you can consider using it.

There also are ways you can play with URL parameters, but then you run the risk of losing it when someone switches pages. It can work, but I tend to avoid that.

I have not seen any components that handle cookies directly, but it shouldn't be too hard to build one.

Here is the gist for cookie management code I use for a recent app. Feel free to wrap it to build a Web component for cookie management.. as long as you share alike!

https://gist.github.com/deitch/dea1a3a752d54dc0d00a

UPDATE:

component.kitchen has a storage component here http://component.kitchen/components/TylerGarlick/core-resource-storage

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanation and recommendation. 

I got the idea. 
- **option1**: the client has to make api request when the index.html is hit to refill the user object *(only when it is hit by refreshing)*. 
- **option 2**: the client has to store the user object somewhere invalatile for a certain amount of time.

Comment: A pleasure. Pretty much, yeah. I have to convert an Angular app to Polymer in the next few weeks, client storage is a big part of it, so we will see how well it plays out in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way if you use PHP is to keep the user in a PHP session (like a normal non SPA application).
PHP will store the user info on the server, and generate automatically a cookie that the browser will send with any request. With a single server with no load balancing, the session data is local and very fast.

Comment: Thanks! Yes you're right. I found that, even if it is an api request, once I log into the service the session variable is passed through the COOKIE and kept for two hours in case of Laravel 5. So, as long as there is a subsequent api request to the server within two hours, the COOKIE extend its life.

Comment: But, I also found that I poorly composed the question subject. It should be something like "keeping user data returned from backend after refreshing the client". What that means is that in terms of api request, once a client gets authenticated there is no restriction to make another api request. But the user object returned from the server is gone.

Comment: I guess there is 2 simple ways to do that :
 - server side : if your server is mostly doing REST requests, you can in your html pages send the user object directly in an onload event if the user is connected : (inside your html templates, use something like window.onload = function() { user = {'JS code generated from the server is a user is connected'};}
I don't know Laravel, but if you have some kind of template engine that can display some JS on every HTML page is the user is connected, it could work
 - client side with a session storage (HTML5 browsers only). See deitch msg for details

Comment: thanks man! I know it's easy to load a login view from the server and then save the user object to the JS window namespace. The client app is a cordova. In case of Android there was no problem using server side, but in iPhone they are doing airplane mode test. Meaning that no page is coming up in airplane mode, they reject the app application. That is the reason why I want to completely decouple the client(mobile app) and server. Anyway thanks to you and community, I got the solution for this.